# Login using Facebook or google+

Tags: authentication, facebook-login, google-signin, identity-column

I have a web app which requires user to register and login to use it. In the database, i have a serial number for every user that is auto generated. The buisness logic uses these serial number to identify users and not their username or email id. Now if i login using Facebook or google +, how to proceed? without a serial number, the buisness logic fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can auto register the user while making them log into the system by google or fb. Then you can easily auto generate the serial numbers as per your business logic.

You will get more insight by checking this link http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/11/login-with-google-api-php

Comment: Is the serial number going to be the same everytime they login?

Comment: My database however generates same serial number sometime later and that conflicts the identity of two people

Comment: yeah it will be same just like in case of normal user logging in your system again.

Comment: which db are you using?

Comment: For now I'm using hsqldb

Comment: I will be moving to a different db real soon